# R: Error when running rattle() - "Invalid root element: 'requires'"

Tags: r, rattle

I installed `rattle` package and associated `GTK+` library for windows (I work in Windows 7, R version 3.4.0). No issues installing them.
The `library(rattle)` command runs ok (no error messages), however when I run `rattle()` I got this error:

```
Error in method(obj, ...) : Invalid root element: 'requires'
```

Any recommendation on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the known compatible version which will definetly work.
1. Try to downgrad your R version to 3.3.2.
2. Download RGtk2 version with 2.20.33 and manually install it.
3. Install rattle version as 4.1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me with this versions.

Answer (score 1):

The development version of rattle (currently 5.0.18) now works with the latest version of RGtk2 (2.20.33) and the earlier version (2.20.31) under recent versions of R.

> install.packages("devtools")
>
> devtools::install_bitbucket("kayontoga/rattle")

Hope that helps.